# How to use f1 score metrics from sklearn using libact?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I used SkeleanrProbaAdapter from [libact](http://libact.readthedocs.io/), to use the Sklearn Gradient Boosting classifier as shown here:

`clf=SklearnProbaAdapter(GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=5, learning_rate=1.0,max_depth=2, random_state=0))`

Following the [example](http://libact.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/plot.html) libact provides in their documentation, I initialized and measure the error in this way:

`qs=UncertaintySampling(trn_ds1, method='lc', model=clf)
model = clf
...training and labeling... 
E_out = np.append(E_out, 1 - model.score(tst_ds))`

Now I am trying to use f1 metrics from libact. I tried

`E_out = np.append(E_out, 1 - model.score(tst_ds, criterion="f1"))`

but since model is not multilabel, an error is raised. Any help deeply appreciated.

Comment: And whats that error? What do you mean by the model is not multilabel? Please provide details.

Comment: Yes, sorry the error was  that libact when you use the SklearnProbaAdapter creates a libact.base.dataset module. But in order to use "criterion="f1"" I needed libact.models.multilabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using  sklearn.metrics f1 score. Here is the code if someone finds this useful:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score 
def run(trn_ds, tst_ds, lbr, model, qs, quota,fully_labeled_trn_ds,train_each,labels):
    E_in, E_out, E_full,E_out_f1 = [], [],[],[]
    counter=0
    for i in range(quota):
        # Standard usage of libact objects
        ask_id = qs.make_query()
        X, _ = zip(*trn_ds.data)
        _, Y = zip(*fully_labeled_trn_ds.data)
        lb = lbr.label(X[ask_id])
        trn_ds.update(ask_id, lb)
        if counter%train_each==0:
            model.train(trn_ds)
        E_in = np.append(E_in, 1 - model.score(trn_ds))
        E_out = np.append(E_out, 1 - model.score(tst_ds))
        E_full= np.append(E_full, 1 - model.score(fully_labeled_trn_ds))
        E_out_f1 = np.append(E_out_f1, f1_score(Y,model.predict(X),average='micro'))
    return E_in, E_out, E_full,E_out_f1
```

I just changed that part in the run function that is called inside active_learning function in the example of libact.